# How do I restore my keybindings?

Tags: shortcut

My cat walked across my keyboard, and now certain key functions have changed (in several programs, actually). Now, things like "Save" are mapped to "Ctrl - W". I tried changing my config back to the "Blender 2.7x" but nothing changes. What did my cat do!?

Comment: maybe put your cat back on your keyboard  ^^

Comment: clearly she knew what she was doing better than I.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you indicated this is occurring across several programs, and therefore is not likely related to blender specifically.

Comment: Other applications fixed after a restart. Blender has not.

Comment: Better ask the cat which keys she stepped on in that case...

Answer (score 0):

I am not a qualified person to post an answer, but I will recommend you look across the internet for an original copy of Program Files(x84)\yourversionofBlender\scripts\presets\keyconfig that can be accessed from File Explorer on your PC.

Replacing the keyconfig file with original data should solve this problem.

If you were asking how to recover your initial personalized key bindings. I'm afraid you'll have to start over after you reset them. Good luck.